# XNA 4.0 && XACT 3.0 wrong version for pipeline framework

Tags: c#, xna, xact

So I'm making a small game for one of my last classes in university.
Basically I'm having some really awful issues trying to play a song in the title screen, then when the user clicks to start game, switching to a game play song.

The first 3 hours, I used the provided sound libraries, and then I ran into the issue many others have with massive lag to the game. So, I decided to give XACT 3 a try, the one packaged with XNA 4.0.

I made the project from scratch, in XACT 3, and XNA is telling me:

error : The .xap file was created with a version of XACT that is incompatible with the XNA Framework Content Pipeline version used by this project. Refer to the documentation for options to resolve this mismatch.

Now i'd love to refer to the non-existent documentation to find out they can't help, but can anyone out there please help me? I'm so close to being finished. My searches for the last few hours have shown me to clues..

Comment: From my experiences with XNA you are trying to use XNA3 stuff with XNA4. Eventually this [post](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/grozen/archive/2010/10/23/converting-a-3d-xna-3-0-game-to-xna-4-0-an-example.aspx) help you.

Comment: Thanks for the try, but above I clearly stated that i'm using XNA 4.0 and the XACT 3 which comes packaged with it. The only way it could actually be a legitimate mismatch is if Microsoft packaged the wrong version of XACT3 with XNA 4.0(which I wouldn't doubt, but I can't find any relevant information on that).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After countless hours, it was of course something stupid.

When you load the XACT3 .XGS, .XSB, .XWB files into the solution explorer(Content in my case), you MUST also make sure to click on the properties of each one and make sure that Build Action is set to NONE.

The error was thrown because XNA didn't know how to build those files, and in true MS fashion, the errors are usually quite confusing and never really take you to the real problem.

Also, for future visitors, make sure you also set Copy to Output to ALWAYS.